# Set the textfield values to an array in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I need to assign the text input values to the variable that I created and than send it to the server. I did everything but the textfields since the iOS development is new for me.

So, I need to set data from the email textfield to the parameters variable and password field as well so I can use that parameters variable in my .post method.

```
   import Alamofire
   import UIKit

   class InitialViewController: UIViewController {

let url = "https://api.sis.kemoke.net/auth/login"
let parameters = ["email": "example@example.com", "password": "examplePassword"]

// Parameters textfields
@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

// A method for the login button
@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: nil).responseJSON {
        (response) in
        print(response.result.value!)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

}

Comment: You haven't provided nearly enough information. The only hint about text fields is that the code you posted included 2 outlets to text fields. That implies that those are the fields who's data you nee to post. However, you haven't given any information about how the data is supposed to be formatted and sent. You said something about assigning input variables "to the variable that I created" but you don't say what variable that is.

Comment: As written, this is a really bad SO question. You should either edit it to provide a clear, complete description of the problem you're trying to solve, or delete it since it's pointless in it's current form.

Comment: Take a look at the variable let parameters among the first lines. It needs to receive data from two textfields.

Comment: in what format?

Comment: Ok, I edited the question. It should be a string and should keep the "email" and "password" parameters. The only thing that should be altered by the textfield is the example email and example password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you can't modify the value of `parameters` since it is declared as a constant (using the `let` keyword). If you want to modify the values, you'll need to declare it as a variable (using the `var` keyword).

Second, you can't expect that outlets will automagically change the values captured inside of the textfields. That said, considering the `text` property of `UITextField` is optional, you might want to validate the content first.

This is an example of what you're trying to achieve:

import Alamofire
import UIKit

```
class InitialViewController: UIViewController {

    let url = "https://api.sis.kemoke.net/auth/login"
    var parameters = ["email": "example@example.com", "password": "examplePassword"]

    // Parameters textfields
    @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

    // A method for the login button
    @IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        parameters["email"] = email.text ?? ""
        parameters["password"] = password.text ?? ""
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: nil).responseJSON {
            (response) in
            print(response.result.value!)
        }
    }

}
```